# Does redux-saga store any status within the redux store?

Tags: redux, reducers, saga, redux-saga

I'm interesting in learning more about redux-saga and I'm curious if it could help out with a problem I would like to solve. Generally for async API calls there are various common patterns around the status of the running *task* such as *did it fail*, *is it still running*, or *did it complete successfully*. I've been implementing these as separate actions that are dispatched but for each API call I'm finding I have at least 3 corresponding actions that I have to name and manage and dispatch separately. To alleviate this I'm looking to implement an abstraction of my own but would first like to verify whether redux-saga includes some standard way of keeping track of these status values on API calls that I could use instead of reinventing the wheel.

Perhaps there are other libraries out there that may help but because I'm interested in redux-saga for other reasons I want to know primarily whether it provides what I'm after.

Comment: Good question! This is what bothers me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redux-saga's main purpose is to handle complex async operations that span across multiple actions (like login, then call authorization api, then refresh authorization each x seconds until user logout).

redux-saga allows you to modify the state by dispatching actions to the store but it doesn't automatically update some status on some request. You'll have to tell it when and where to store the status. So maybe it's not *directly* useful for your case.